# create a flask model with 4 classes containing a 1:M join and a M:M join involving the User class

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login, flask-admin

I am brand new to Flask. I am trying to create a flask app for a local community group where they can add in comments and organise events or support. I have create the login system (using on-line resources) and I have installed the flask-admin so there is an overview of incoming messages.

I want to restrict access to the admin panel so that only somebody who is the admin user can see all the posts/messages. Some of the posts might be confidential.

To do this I thought using basic-auth would be fine. I researched the data model for flask-roles so I could assign admin role and 'the rest'. (I just want a single admin user) and I went ahead and created what I thought was a reasonable model where the user class has a 1:M with posts class and a M:M with the roles class through the userroles class

```
from datetime import datetime
from flaskblog import db, login_manager
from flaskblog import app
from flask_login import UserMixin
from flaskblog import routes
from flask_admin import Admin
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
admin = Admin(app, name='Dashboard')

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
return User.query.get(int(user_id))

class UserRoles(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'user_roles'
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
__tablename__ = 'users'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)

def __repr__(self):
return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.image_file}')"


class Post(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
date_related = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
user = relationship("User")

def __repr__(self):
return f"Post('{self.title}', '{self.date_posted},', '{self.date_related},')"

class Role(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'role'
id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))
```

I have been stuck for days trying to get this to work. I’ve researched lots of different ways of getting it to work, but I come up with the same error message all the time. Any ideas? Am I completely barking up the wrong tree? When I go into python CLI and use "from flaskblog import models" this is the error message.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.roles - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'user_roles'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.
```

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't critical, my suggestion would be to make the roles an attribute of Users and not the other way around. So, you'd update UserRoles to be like:

```
class UserRoles(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'user_roles'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
  user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
  role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

and Users to be:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
  __tablename__ = 'users'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
  email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
  image_file = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
  password = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
  roles = relationship("UserRoles")
```

and Role to be:

```
class Role(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'role'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, db.ForeignKey(User.id))
  name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
```

This way when you call the User object, you can access the list of roles they have by calling the "roles" attribute and iterating through a list.

I think that should address the FK not found issue. If not let me know what the revised stack trace is.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, really grateful for your quick response. I've tried what you suggested and I still get the same annoying error. I'm wondering whether I shouldn't just create a flag in the user model and then set it to true if I want the user to have access to the admin panel.

Just to be clear, the following happens when I type in from "flaskblog import models"

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/david/course/project1/overton_playgroup/flaskblog/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flaskblog import routes
  File "/home/david/course/project1/overton_playgroup/flaskblog/routes.py", line 6, in <module>
    from flaskblog.forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm, UpdateAccountForm, PostForm
  File "/home/david/course/project1/overton_playgroup/flaskblog/forms.py", line 7, in <module>
    from flaskblog.models import User
  File "/home/david/course/project1/overton_playgroup/flaskblog/models.py", line 64, in <module>
    admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 330, in __init__
    menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 818, in __init__
    self._refresh_cache()
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 895, in _refresh_cache
    self._list_columns = self.get_list_columns()
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/model/base.py", line 1035, in get_list_columns
    only_columns=self.column_list or self.scaffold_list_columns(),
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 418, in scaffold_list_columns
    for p in self._get_model_iterator():
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/view.py", line 354, in _get_model_iterator
    return model._sa_class_manager.mapper.iterate_properties
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 2065, in iterate_properties
    configure_mappers()
  File "/home/david/course/project1/venv_name/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 3251, in configure_mappers
    raise e
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: One or more mappers failed to initialize - can't proceed with initialization of other mappers. Triggering mapper: 'mapped class User->user'. Original exception was: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship User.roles - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'user_roles'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.
```